# Degrading the services automatically by autoscaling in azure services - vCPU

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-machine-learning-service

I am designing a learning management system and inflow for the website is more in some cases and  less in another time. I would like to know about the getting the vCPU's which are scaled up to make it down after the stipulated time. I found a document regarding [scaling up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/auto-scaling) but didn't find a way to scale it down.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance of auto scaling for the normal services in azure cloud services, that means for stipulated time you can increase or decrease as mentioned in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-how-to-scale-portal).

When it comes for vCPU which is cannot be performed automatically. vCPU can be scaled up based on the request criteria and in the same manner we need to request the support team to scale those down to the normal.

**There is no specific procedure to make the auto scaling for vCPU operations. We can increase the capacity of core, but to reduce to the normal, we need to approach the support system for manual changing. You can change it from 10 cores to next level 16 cores, but cannot be performed automatic scaling down from 16 cores to 10 cores.**

Comment: Hi @Sairam Thanks for the information. If you have any official document which states that the procedure is not acceptable, kindly share that link also.